# Endpoint que devuelve array de objetos filtrados

Tags: javascript, nodejs, poo, arraylist

estoy trabada con este problema que seguramente es mas sencillo de lo que creo, tengo este array de objetos de ejemplo:

```
  "peliculas": [
    {
        "_id": "620a5b2063b3d902d504da2d",
        "imagen": "titanic.png",
        "titulo": "titanic",
        "historia": "historia titanic",
        "director": "james cameron",
        "createdAt": "2022-02-14T13:37:36.961Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-02-14T13:37:36.961Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "620a822a82fef9682ab2b5c4",
        "imagen": "resplandor.png",
        "titulo": "el resplandor",
        "historia": "el resplandor hitoria",
        "director": "stanley kubrick",
        "createdAt": "2022-02-14T16:24:10.836Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-02-14T16:24:10.836Z"
    }
]
```

y necesito hacer un endpoint metodo get que me devuelva el siguiente array:

```
"peliculas": [
    {
        "imagen": "titanic.png",
        "titulo": "titanic",

    },
    {
        "imagen": "resplandor.png",
        "titulo": "el resplandor",
    }
```

probe con el metodo map pero me devuelve un array simple:

```
"peliculas": [
    "titanic.png",
    "titanic",
    "resplandor.png",
    "el resplandor"
]
```

Comment: Hola, vas por buen camino... haciendo una pequeña modificación al `map`, seguro lo logras, que has intentado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No quiero darte la respuesta completa, ya que no haz puesto lo que haz intentado, pero te dare las siguientes pistas por el momento:

El metodo `map` permite transformar un `array` y que en cada pocision de su memoria se devuelva el valor de retorno de tu condicion, al final devuelve el arreglo transformado.

Por ejemplo:

```
{
   return true
}
```

dentro del callback del metodo `map` haria que todas las pocisiones de memoria automaticamente se conviertan en `true`.

Ahora bien, el metodo `map` le puedes pasar un `callback` y el `callback` a su vez puede recibir dos parametros, el primero siempre sera el valor del elemento en esa iteración y el segundo el indice de la iteración:

```
function(elemento, indice){

}
```

Por lo que puedes recorrer cada uno de tus objetos con `map` y crear por ej, un nuevo objeto y guardar en el las propiedades con los valores que necesitas.

Una vez creado el objeto lo podrias retornar.

Este ultimo paso es el que te queda como tarea, veamos como intentas resolverlo.

Comment: Gracias!!!!!! me sirvio muchisimo tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolverlo, asi quedo mi controlador despues de quemar varias neuronas, cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida, el indice en este caso no hizo falta. funciona perfecto gracias!!

```
export const getMovies = async (req, res) => {
const movies = await Movie.find();  
const result = movies.map(function (movie, index) {    
var moviesN = new Object()     
moviesN.imagen = character.imagen     
moviesN.titulo= character.titulo     
return (moviesN)})     
res.json({ Movies:  result })};
```

Comment: Despues de pasado 1 dia, el usuario que creo la pregunta puede dar su propia respuesta como aceptada, eso te dara puntos, resolviste por completo tu duda?, si es asi, deberias darle click al chulo que aparece en tu respuesta, asi recibiras puntos por respuesta.